# cxGrid boolean type group summary item

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I have a field (OK) in my cxGrid which is displayed as a checkbox (properties : checkbox). It is an actual database field (boolean) in my SQLite database . Can I group this field so that the grid displays how many items are checked and how many are not (default for groups) ? Right now I managed only to count the items.

[image]

The display I have now is something like this :

[image]

I need to count checked and unchecked items. Is this possible at all?

EDIT : 
In one similar program I have such a feature implemented below) :

[image]

Here the sum works since it sums up numbers. In this case I dont know how to sum up
true/false thing... The best next thing I came up in this example is this :

[image]

Just changed the field name from 'ok' to' urejeno' ....

Comment: It displays 2 groups (true/false) and shows how many items in every group, isn't it? For example number of items in group TRUE is number of checked items, you already have everything what you are asking for. What is the problem?

Comment: I need to display the count of how many true and how many false.

Comment: eeem... I want to have the count displayed all in one row

Comment: If you want to have only number in group cell (without caption etc), then you have to implement OnCustomDrawGroupRow event handler and draw what you want, for example just number of items in the group. Number of child items in group "true" - it is number of checked items, number of child items in group "false" - it is number of unchecked items.

Comment: I already have the total number of items displayed (next to the date).However I want to display (next to the total items) the display of how many true and how many false.

Comment: Use OnCustomDrawGroupCell event to display what you want.